# How to fix a jQuery scroll problem?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

Can someone help me with a small bug, pls? Here’s the demo: http://dev.template-tuners.com/custom-slider/

When hover on 3rd item will have “active” class and remains opened. But if scroll to right, first click is ok, but on 2nd click returns from begining.

Also if 2nd item is active, on click next arrow, no movement :(

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. I using Chrome 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on my test, everything fine. when i click scroll the last active image(taller image) is in correct index on both scroll left and right. and i clicked both for several times.
i'm using firefox

but it has glitch. maybe disabled active on click would help. becus when i click on image continuously its kinda weired

Answer (score 0):

also on click to show a caption, if you see in code there's a `div.caption` for every item:
Now on click the sliders is moving..

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""><img src="thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="caption">
        <h2>Coat with Knitted Collar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ante tellus, molestie ut eleifend nec, lobortis non nisi. Sed quis lacus quis turpis auctor.</p>
        <a href="#" title="">View Composition and care</a>
    </div>
</li>
```